# é melhor uma busca binaria recursiva ou iterativa?

Tags: busca-binária

Não faço PAA(Projeto e Análise de algoritmos) mas gostaria de saber qual o custo de fazer uma busca binaria recursiva e o custo da busca iterativa, para um trabalho de Estrutura de dados. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Defina melhor. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39226/101, provavelmente é duplicata